# Finding the all roots of a polynomial by using Newton-Raphson method.

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots, complex-dynamics

Is there a general formulation for finding all roots of a *polynomial*, especially the complex ones, by using the Newton-Raphson Method?

Comment: The Newton-Raphson method converges rapidly to an *isolated* root of an equation or system of equations involving smooth functions once we have an approximation *close enough* to that root.  Unfortunately these "basins of attraction" often have a fractal pattern, so making a broad generalization about how to be sure you are close enough is impossible.  See the discussion [here on Julia sets](http://classes.yale.edu/fractals/mandelset/complexnewton/newtonbasins/newtonbasins.html).

Comment: There is also a difficulty in knowing when a root has multiplicity greater than one, or when two roots that have multiplicity one happen to lie closely together.

Comment: Do you want (all) complex roots of polynomials in one variable?

Comment: yes, I want this

Comment: N-R is never used by itself, in general : it must be used in combination with a root bracketing method, such as bisection.

Comment: @user_of_math The question is mostly about complex roots.

Comment: In short, no. Even when it can converge to a root, the convergence can be arbitrarily slow, so you can never be sure you're close. See what happens for $(x-1)^{50}$ for example.

Comment: I've added the complex-dynamics tag as the solution I've referred to below depends fundamentally on that area of study.

Comment: Use [Laguerre's Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre's_method).

Comment: @hardmath The *boundaries* of the basins have a fractal structure but the basins themselves are open sets and extend out to infinity in a uniform way, thus it is possible to pick a set of initial seeds to ensure that you capture all the roots. Furthermore, the multiplicity of each root is reflected in the rate of convergence to the root - though, you are right that this is difficult to detect for large multiplicity. The details are all contained in the paper linked in my answer.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy The `NewtonSolve` command I outline below finds the roots of your polynomial in 0.2 seconds.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: My initial comments preceded the narrowing of the Question to *polynomial* equations (in one variable).  Indeed the multiple roots may be detectable by GCD, depending on the polynomial's coefficients are known or it appears merely as a "black box" for evaluation (function and derivative since the Newton iterations are contemplated).

Comment: @hardmath Indeed, I did not know that the question was originally confined to polynomials! Nonetheless, my comment seems apropos, given the new context.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes, there is such a method!  See the aptly named "[How to find all roots of complex polynomials by Newton's method](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehubbard/NewtonInventiones.pdf)", by Hubbard, Schliecher, and Sutherland.

Not only is there a method but, due to the stability of the fixed points under iteration of the Newton's method function, there is a *very good* method.  Indeed, the authors point out that they were led to this topic in their study of invariant measures of the Henon mapping and, in that context had a genuine need to find roots of polynomials whose degree was several thousand.  Evidently, their method succeeded where established software tools failed.

The basic idea is to find a collection of initial seeds distributed in such a way that you are guaranteed that, for each root, there is at least one of the seeds that converges to that root.  This set is quite large but you can quit when you've found all the roots. The multiplicity of the root can be determined by the rate of convergence.

I've included an implementation in Mathematica below called `NewtonSolve`.  Here's an example:

```
NewtonSolve[(z^3 - 1) (z - I)^3, z, 
  ErrorTolerance -> 10^-20] // Chop
(* Out: {{2.34482*10^-8 + 1. I, 1}, {0. + 1. I, 3}, 
   {-0.5 + 0.866025 I, 1}, {-0.5 - 0.866025 I, 1}}
*)
```

Note that the command returns a list of `{root,multiplicity}` pairs and that $i$ has been correctly identified as having multiplicity 3.  Of course, there are polynomials that will mess up any root finder and I make no claims that this code is production quality - but it does illustrate the ideas.

Here's a picture that further illustrates what's going on with this example:

[image]

The large green dots are exactly the roots of the polynomial - each living inside its shaded basin of attraction.  The fundamental observation in the paper is that each of these basins of attraction extends off to infinity.  As a result, we can choose a large enough ring of initial seeds so that each basin of attraction contains one of the seeds.  The ring for this particular polynomial (in fact, any polynomial of degree six with roots in the unit disk) is shown as the ring of black dots.

The function solves an allegedly difficult example proposed in the comments above, with correct multiplicity, in well under a second:

```
NewtonSolve[(z - 1)^50, z] // Timing
(* Out: {0.293804, {{1. + 0. I, 50}}} *)
```

---

Here's the code for `NewtonSolve`:

```
Options[NewtonSolve] = {
   NormalizationFactor -> Automatic,
   ErrorTolerance -> $MachineEpsilon
   };
NewtonSolve[poly_, var_,
   opts___] := Module[
    {p, z, nwt, cp, cpp,
     coeffs, deg, maxRootRadius,
     mult, sameRootQ, newRootQ,
     maxIters, rootsSoFar, initPoints,
     numInitPoints, rmPair, normFactor,
     tol},

    normFactor = NormalizationFactor /. {opts} /. 
      Options[NewtonSolve];
    tol = ErrorTolerance /. {opts} /.
      Options[NewtonSolve];

    coeffs = CoefficientList[poly, var];
    deg = Length[coeffs] - 1;
    If[normFactor === Automatic,
     maxRootRadius = Max[Abs[Drop[coeffs, -1]/Last[coeffs]]] + 1,
     maxRootRadius = normFactor];
    p[z_] = poly /. var -> maxRootRadius*z;

    cp = Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, p[z]];
    cpp = Compile[{{z, _Complex}}, Evaluate[p'[z]]];
    nwt = Compile[{{z, _Complex}},
      Evaluate[z - p[z]/p'[z]]];
    mult[z0_Complex] := If[nwt[z0] == z0, 1,
      mult[FixedPointList[nwt, z0, 1000]]];
    mult[orbit_List] := Module[{f, div, diffs},
      f[x_] := If[x != 1.0, 1/(x - 1)];
      div[{a_, b_}] := If[b != 0, a/b];
      diffs = Abs[(#[[2]] - #[[1]]) & /@ 
         Partition[Drop[orbit, -1], 2, 1]];
      statisticalMode[Round[f /@ (div /@ 
             Partition[diffs, 2, 1])] + 1  /. Round[_] -> 0]];
    sameRootQ[z1_, z2_, 1] := If[Abs[cp[z1]] >= Abs[cp[z2]],
      Abs[z1 - z2] <= Abs[3 cp[z1]/cpp[z1]],
      Abs[z2 - z1] <= Abs[3 cp[z2]/cpp[z2]]];
    sameRootQ[z1_, z2_, mm_ /; mm > 1] := Abs[z1 - z2] < 100 tol;
    newRootQ[z_, mm_] := Module[{justRootsSoFar, flag},
      flag = True;
      justRootsSoFar = First /@ Flatten[rootsSoFar];
      Scan[If[sameRootQ[#, z, mm], Return[flag = False]] &,
       justRootsSoFar];
      flag];
    maxIters = 
     Ceiling[(Log[1 + Sqrt[2]] - Log[tol])/(
      Log[deg] - Log[deg - 1])];
    rootsSoFar = {};
    numRootsSoFar = 0;
    initPoints = N[S[deg]];
    numInitPoints = Length[initPoints];

    i = 0;
    While[i++ < numInitPoints  && numRootsSoFar < deg,
     orbit = NestWhileList[nwt, initPoints[[i]],
       (Abs[cp[#1]] >= tol && #1 != #2) &, 2, maxIters];
     nextRoot = Last[orbit];
     If[(Abs[cp[nextRoot]] < tol || orbit[[-2]] == orbit[[-1]]),
      m = mult[nextRoot];
      If[m > 1,
       nextRoot = FixedPoint[nwt, nextRoot, maxIters]];
      If[newRootQ[nextRoot, m],
       numRootsSoFar = numRootsSoFar + m;  
       rootsSoFar = {rootsSoFar, rmPair[nextRoot, m]}]]
     ];
    Flatten[rootsSoFar] /. rmPair[r_, mm_] -> 
      {r*maxRootRadius, mm}
    ] /; (PolynomialQ[poly, var] && 
     NumericQ[poly /. var :> Random[]]);

statisticalMode[list_] :=
      Module[{c, mc, ms},
            c = {Length[#], First[#]} & /@ Split[Sort[list]];
            If[Length[c] === 1, Return[c[[1, 2]]]];
            mc = Max[First[Transpose[c]]];
            If[mc === 1, Return[{}]];
            ms = Cases[c, {mc , val_} -> val];
            If[Length[ms] == 1, ms[[1]], ms];
    ms[[1]]] /; VectorQ[list] && (Length[list] > 0);
statisticalMode[{}] = 1;

ring[r_, d_] := With[{n = Ceiling[8.32547 d Log[d]]},
   Flatten[Transpose[Partition[Table[r Exp[2 Pi I j/n], 
       {j, 0, n - 1}], Ceiling[n/d], Ceiling[n/d], 1, {{}}]]]];
S[d_] := With[{R = 1 + Sqrt[2], s = Ceiling[0.26632 Log[d]]},
   Flatten[Table[ring[R (1 - 1/d)^((2 \[Nu] - 1)/(4 s)), d],
     {\[Nu], 1, s}]]];
```

Comment: Nice answer! Didn't know of something like this for complex roots.

Comment: @user_of_math Glad you like it!  I added a little further explanation with a picture.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thanks!

Comment: @MJD Thanks for the bounty!

Answer (score 5):

As has been pointed out, the Newton-Raphson, as well as most other such methods, converge to a single isolated root. There are, however, methods to find all roots of a polynomial.

One I know of, is creating the [companion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix), and then finding (numerically) that matrix's eigenvalues, which are precisely the roots of your polynomial.

If you use Matlab, this is precisely what the 'roots' routine does. From personal experience with that routine, it runs very fast for polynomial of both low and high degrees.

Answer (score 0):

While in general the answer is no, there is the [Weierstrass method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand%E2%80%93Kerner_method), which is based on multi-dimensional Newton's method and attempts to find all complex roots. Much like Newton's method it's not guaranteed to succeed, and only works well when the roots are simple.

Weierstrass method is probably closest to what you are looking for.