# Real roots of an nth order polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

Given an nth order polynomial, is there any algorithm that can calculate all the roots ? Is there any algorithm that can calculate ALL the roots of the equation ?

$$p(x)=p_nx^n+p_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+p_1x+p_0$$

All coefficients are real, and I'm only looking for real roots.

Comment: Are you looking for a numerical algorithm for approximate solutions or an algebraic algorithm for "closed form" solutions?

Comment: [Mark McClure's answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998333/finding-the-all-roots-of-a-polynomial-by-using-newton-raphson-method) deserves some more upvotes. He beautifully  summarizes a recent paper,  "[How to find all roots of complex polynomials by Newton's method](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/NewtonInventiones.pdf)", by Hubbard, Schliecher, and Sutherland, that does just what you want: "Not only is there a method but, due to the stability of the fixed points under iteration of the Newton's method function, there is a *very good* method."

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Approximations are just fine.

Comment: @MJD From what I managed to understand, it does not give any assurance that the roots can be found in linear time. If any two of the roots are too close, I think it would take a long time to finish selecting the seeds

Comment: I believe you are mistaken.  See the section on page 5 that begins "concerning the number of iterations...".

Comment: @MJD that solves it, thanks :)